# Weekly Cron Job on a Specific Day

Tags: cron

I created the following cron job yesterday to run every Tuesday at 12:01 AM (I think), but it did not run last night. Running the command as I have it in the cron file works. What did I get wrong here?

```
1 0 * * 2 python2.7 /path/to/django/manage.py my_command > /path/to/file.log
```

EDIT: I wasn't including the log redirect and I'm guessing that might be important. Should it be >>

Comment: did you check the environment? Try `cat /etc/crontab` to check the shell, `$PATH` etc

Answer (score 1):

Possibly `python2.7` is not in the default `PATH` that `cron` provides to the jobs it spawns, as @Zhenya points out. Usually `cron` logs somewhere, but it seems to vary by distribution - on my Debian box, `syslog` redirects these entries to `/var/log/syslog`, but it may be a different log file on your box. Check to see what errors `cron` may be complaining about...